# Problems array and char

Tags: c

I'm new to programming. I can't find errors in this code.
I'm trying to translate some characters to numbers.

The program ask to enter a message, but after I entered the characters nothing show up.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 100

int main (void)
{
    char message[N];
    int i;
    printf ("Enter a message: ");

    for (i=0; i<N; i++){
        scanf ("%c", &message[i]);
    }
    // characters are in the array

    for (i=0; i<N; i++){
        if (message[i]=='a')
            message[i]='4';
        if (message[i]=='b')
            message[i]='8';
        if (message[i]=='e')
            message[i]='3';
        if (message[i]=='i')
            message[i]='1';
        if (message[i]=='o')
            message[i]='0';
        if (message[i]=='s')
            message[i]='5';
    }
    // characters are translated

    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        printf ("%c ", message[i]);
    // characters are printed

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To start with, `scanf ("%c", &message[i]);` --> `scanf (" %c", &message[i]);`

Comment: Your program isn't going to do anything until you enter 100 characters.  Is that the intent?

Comment: Try this : http://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/J0LvwM

Comment: `if(message[i] == '\n') break;`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply read the whole message by using `scanf("%s",message);`

That way you don't have to wait for all the 100 characters to be entered and you can check with whatever input (maybe less than 100 characters) you have given. Same way you can print it using `printf`

```
printf("%s",message);
```

Use `switch` for doing the characters change based on different cases.

```
switch(message[i]){
   case 'a': message[i]='4';break;
   ...
}
```

Instead of looping for all `N` characters loop till `strlen(message)` or `message[i]!='\0'`

Answer (score 0):

What compiler do you use? Your code works well in https://www.jdoodle.com/c-online-compiler. 
For this case, if I understand exactly, you can better get a complete message, use:

```
scanf("%s", message);
```

instead of:

```
for (i=0; i<N; i++){
scanf ("%c", &message[i]);
}
```